# Cannot get port forwarding to work

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I want to access multiple ESP8266 in my home network from an outside network. The problem I'm facing is, although I've forwarded some ports on my router I'm not able to access it from outside networks.

I have created an account with noip.com to get a dynamic DNS domain and saved it in my router too. But I still can't talk to my ESP or any devices for that matter. I called my ISP about opening ports, they said for that I have to call my local operator to assign me a live IP and then again call the ISP to open the desired ports.

So I wanted to ask if this really works like that? Because I have seen in many forums, blogs, videos that port forwarding can be done from my end. So why do I need to call my ISP for that. And even if I have to call the ISP to open ports, I already have dynamic DNS domain set up, so can I just ask my ISP to open ports without getting (or moving whatever) to live IP?

Comment: I use No-IP, and the service works fine for me. Have you installed their DUC (dynamic update client) and is it running? When you Ping your No-IP address, does it show your public IP (as shown by your router or https://www.whatismyip.com/)?

Comment: What ISP are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> they said for that I have to call my local operator to assign me a live IP and then again call the ISP to open the desired ports.

That's a bit confusing. What's a "live" IP? Do they mean a *public* address? Do they mean *static*? (Do they mean "energized with 220V"?) And who's the "local operator" if it's not the ISP itself?

But...

> I called my ISP about opening ports, they said for that I have to call my local operator to assign me a live IP and then again call the ISP to open the desired ports.
>
> I have seen in many forums, blogs, videos that port forwarding can be done from my end. So why do I need to call my ISP for that.

In the past, yes.

Now, unfortunately, more and more ISP are finding that they have *more customers than IPv4 addreses* – and they cannot obtain more IPv4 addresses because all registries have already run out, as well.

As a result, some ISPs add a 2nd level of NAT, this time on *their* routers (aka "CGNAT"), to allow multiple customers to share a single public IPv4 address. In other words, the address that No-IP sees *is not necessarily yours.*

(Take a look at your router's status page, where it shows the WAN address. If it says that your WAN address is from the private ranges – 10.x, 100.64.x, 172.(16-31).x, or 192.168.x – then the router is itself behind a NAT.)

If you are in that situation, you *do* need to ask the ISP to reserve you an IP address instead of using a shared one. Or something such.